# React - Redux Form and Dropzone onDrop Integration

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form, dropzone.js

I am trying to trigger the onDrop event from Dropzone using Redux-Forms. Currently it is not triggering the event when the file is dropped, but it does get it when you manually select the file to upload. Below is the code:

```
const renderDropZone = ({ input, className }) => {
const file = input.value[0];

return (
    <div>
        <Dropzone
            accept="image/*, application/pdf, application/msword"
            onDrop={filesToUpload => input.onChange(filesToUpload)}
            multiple={false}
            className={className}
            {...input}
        >
            {({ isDragAccept, isDragReject }) => {
                if (isDragAccept) return "Allowed"; 
                if (isDragReject) return "File type not allowed";
                return input.value[0] ? `File ready for upload: ${input.value[0].name}` : "Click or drop file here...";
            }}
        </Dropzone>
        <div>
            <h1>{file ? file.name : 'Upload a file'}</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
)
}
```

Has anyone ran into this problem?

Comment: How are you using `renderDropZone`?

Comment: @ardev this is how I'm using it: <Field component={renderDropZone} name="file" className={classes.dropZone}  />

Comment: ok, you have to pass the `onChange` method as props: `const renderDropZone = ({ input, className, onChange }) => {`

Comment: like here:  https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/docs/api/field.md/#usage

Comment: @ardev Tried it but it's still not recording the file when dropped. It does trigger the isDragAccept or isDragReject events but doesn't set the file as the value.

Comment: what if you destructured the field object like this and made sure that the onDrop prop passes in the method and the value something like this...

    const renderDropZone = ({ ...field }) => {
    
    return (
        <div>
            <Dropzone
                accept="image/*, application/pdf, application/msword"
                onDrop={()=> input.onChange(input.value)}
                multiple={false}
                className={className}
            >
             ...